# Creating a program that asks the user for two numbers and has three possible answers. code not compiling. number(as an int)

Tags: c++

So I recently started with C++ and one challenge is to create a program that asks for two numbers and it has to say either if; one of the numbers is positive, both are positive or neither are positive. I tried to make a switch structure without if's but It does not seem to work out. Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    int number2;

    cout <<"Introduce two numbers:" ;
    cin >> number, number2;
    switch(number)
    {
    case (number > 0) (number2 > 0): cout <<"Both numbers are positive.";
    break;
    case (number > 0) (number2 < 0): cout <<"One of the numbers is positive.";
    break;
    case (number < 0) (number2 > 0): cout <<"One of the numbers is positive.";
    break;
    case (number < 0) (number2 < 0): cout <<"None of the numbers are positive.";
    break;
    default: cout <<"It must be a number.";
}
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation errors I get are the following. 
In function 'int main()':

[Error] 'number' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] 'number2' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] 'number' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] 'number2' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] 'number' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] 'number2' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] 'number' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] 'number2' cannot appear in a constant-expression

[Error] a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression

Comment: You should start with a decent book on the language. You can't input 2 numbers like that, and `case` statements don't behave that way.

Comment: There is no guessing at syntax. If you have even a shred of doubt about the proper syntax or language use -- look it up. It will save you untold amounts of time in the long run. Try something, compile, fail, try something else, compile, fail ... ends up going nowhere.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Stop guessing, start reading.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you are running into is that the cases in a `switch` statement can only take constants.

For example this is valid:

```
switch (number)
{
case 0:
    // Do something because number is 0
    break;
case 1:
    // Do something because number is 1
    break;
case -5:
    break;
//etc...
}
```

Basically you can't use variables after the `case` keyword. So you'll need to use `if`s to do what you want, it isn't possible with a `switch`.

Some more reading on switch-statements:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm